# Use same HTML template in multiple components Angular 5

Tags: angular

Sup!
I have a question:
I have a web app on Angular 5. There are such essence as popup in this app. Popup contains a set of repeated HTML elements. App contains a lot of differrent popups. So i deside create one component named popup-template and placed all the general layout for all popups in it. Inside HTML template i plased few "anchors" like this `<ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>` for header, body and footer content. Now, to create a specific popup, I use a popup-template in its HTML template, and create several blocks with the appropriate labels. But I do not leave the feeling that I'm doing something wrong, and that it would be possible to do the same thing easier. Whatever kind of HTML fragment that could be connected to several components and use it in layout.